# How can i get the last inserted id using select * from query?

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner at php html and css
How can i get another element with the last id using "$SQL=select * from test where id''"query
then display it on a text area?

if you have other suggestions other than select query feel free to do so

Comment: So you're asking how to run queries in MySQL using PHP or how to get the last inserted id in a select query in SQL or how to display it in HTML? Your question really lacks focus

Comment: sorry if its confusing im trying to get last inserted id in a select query in sql and then display on a text area in html